# Why is the content of my question out of scope?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-ness, asking-questions, vote-to-close

[What are the criteria for effective academic journal websites?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/102255/what-are-the-criteria-for-effective-academic-journal-websites)

> This question was put on hold yesterday, the reason being: "This question is not within the scope of this site as defined in the help center. Our scope particularly excludes the content of research, education outside of a university setting, and undergraduate admissions, life, and culture." – Mark, scaaahu, user3209815, Coder, Florian D'Souza

I would like to improve this question so that it is within the scope of the site. I am not clear why the content was decided to be excluded. So, I would appreciate any assistance in identifying why the content is not within the scope of the site. I'll then rectify the problem, and update the question so that it can be reviewed and opened again.

There weren't any comments added by the voters to close.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't have voted to close as out of scope. But I would have voted to close as primarily opinion based, because it's basically a poll. See the [help center](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

(In fact, it got into the close vote review queue in the first place after someone flagged it as "primarily opinion based".)

Comment: Thanks, I think that is a fair reason, why was the current reason chosen?

Comment: @Penanghill: The first close vote may have been mistakenly chosen, and people do tend to “glom on” to the first reason chosen when casting additional close votes.

Comment: @aeismail Thanks I guess so.  Oh well. Probably pointless trying to re-word the question then.